# I need to read a txt file in c and save the dates inside the structure or a list

Tags: c

Here is an example of the txt.

```
ABS 2010-10-11 15:10:10 
PER 2010-10-11 15:10:10 
PER 2010-10-11 15:10:10
```

So far I can easily put data into structure without signs like - or :.
Could some C prodigy try to give me hints on how to avoid this problem. Thanks

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Alarm 
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    char Type[30];


};
void getStructInfo(struct Alarm theStruct){ //just a function to check if data is stored in the structure
    printf("\n");
    printf("Type: %s\n\n",theStruct.Type);
    printf("Godina:%d\n",theStruct.year );
}
int main(){
struct Alarm a1,a2;
FILE *fp; 
fp= fopen("podaci.txt","r");
if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error\n");
    return 1;

}

while(1){

fscanf(fp,"%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",&a1.Type,&a1.year,&a1.month,&a1.day);
printf("%s\t%.4d\t%.2d\t%.2d\n",a1.Type,a1.year,a1.month,a1.day );
printf("Continue reading (y/n)\n");
char ch=getch();
if(ch == 'N' || ch== 'n')
 break;

        }
fclose(fp);
getStructInfo(a1);
return 0;
}
```

the output is like this:
 ABS 2012 -10 -11

Comment: And why did your program fail? Where is it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: Sorry, I added the code now.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, please, take a read "How do I ask a good question?" to improve your chances of getting an answer, and remember show us what are you doing so far to solve you problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: fscanf(fp, "%s %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", a1.Type, &a1.year, &a1.month, &a1.day, &a1.hour, &a1.minute, &a1.second);

Comment: the output when i compile your solution is next: 
ABS 2010 -10 -11 2686732 2686736 2686740

Comment: Concerning your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735374/i-need-to-read-a-txt-file-in-c-and-save-the-dates-inside-the-structure-or-a-list#comment55240185_33735374), suspect you incorrectly left `&` in front of `&a1.hour, &a1.minute, &a1.second` in the new `printf()`

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how fscanf works and use the return-value:

```
while( fscanf(fp, "%s%d-%u-%u%*s",&a1.Type,&a1.year,&a1.month,&a1.day)==4 )
{
  ...
}
```